# How display ValidationMessageFor from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a complication to display a ValidationMessageFor or mvc span, I have a ajax method to check for an id bd and it returns a Boolean me, this result if there want this.

```
function ExistProduct() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Products/ExistProduct",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.exist == true) {
                // show ValidationMessageFor 
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

as I can resolve this and not allow submit apply and save

Comment: Are you wanting to validate that a product exists? If so then use the `RemoteAttribute` [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). Dont try and reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2):

Your Function

```
function ExistProduct() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Products/ExistProduct",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.exist == true) {
                // show ValidationMessageFor 
                jQuery("#valodation_msg").css({"color":"green"});
                jQuery("#valodation_msg").html("Success");
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#valodation_msg").css({"color":"red"});
                jQuery("#valodation_msg").html("Error");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Add One Div to your HTML Code Where you want to show validation msg

```
<div id="valodation_msg"></div>
```

Comment: hello thanks, but to not allow submit, is that possible?

Comment: if I submit this is my code `      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductID, new { htmlAttributes = new { id="txtProductoid",@class = "form-control"} })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div id="valodation_msg"></div>`

Comment: OH... Can You Explain What You Want Exactly?

Comment: ok, I need that when spam is displayed for any errors that the process is similar like ValidationMessageFor, do not accept the submit until the error is resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
function ExistProduct() { 

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/Products/ExistProduct",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            // show ValidationMessageFor 
        var p = document.createElement('p'),
        txt = document.createTextNode("Your validation message");
        p.appendChild(txt);
        document.getElementById("id of the element where u want to  show validation message ").appendChild(p);
        return false;

        }
        else {

        }
    }
});
```

}